# How do I show a django model in admin as a spreadsheet instead of list of objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

in my admin.py, have a model registered:  `admin.site.register(model)`.

In the admin pages, I see my model, as a list of model objects. 
Is there a way to set up the admin model page, to show the list of objects in the form of a spreadsheet, instead of a `__str__` name format?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `__str__` name format ?

Comment: what I meant was that, in admin you see a list of  "model object"s.  If you add __str__ to your model, then "model object" is replaced with the return value of the __str__ function.  I wanted something else than that.  Thanks much.  @GwynBleidD solved it.  Thanks for looking tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display any field of your model in column by creating custom admin class for particular model.

Simply subclass `ModelAdmin` and give it `list_display` attribute that will contain list of names of your fields. They will be displayed as separate columns. You can also create custom columns, all is described in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: every where you turn, django has a solution.  Thank you very much.  This worked.